# Javascript change text of Radio button

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using following Method in Javascript.

```
Function JsChangeRBText(itemCheckBox, rbClientId)
{
   var optVal = document.getElementById(rbClientId);
   if(itemCheckjBox.checked)
   {
        optVal.innerText = 'abc';
    }       
   else
   {
        optVal.innerText = 'xyz';
    }       
}
```

here rbclientId is client id of radio button. I want to change its text on a check box checked or unchecked condition. But using above code I am unable to it.Am I missing something. I also tried for innerHTML. When I am using alert to get the current text using innerText and innerHTML, both are blank. But in alert I can see rbClientId's id and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function JsChangeRBText(itemCheckBox, rbClientId)
{
   var optVal = document.getElementById(rbClientId);
   var label =  optVal.nextSibling;
   if(itemCheckjBox.checked)
   {
     label.value = "adc";;
   }       
   else
   {
     label.value = "ccc";
   }       
}
```

Comment: but current label.value is undefined.

Comment: Control not going inside the If condition. I think some problem in method next().

Comment: Can you post the asp control markup in your question... and also how you call the js function..

Comment: @ A.V. Thankyou so much. your very first answer solved this. using optVal.nextSibling. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" /><label>Option 1</label>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" /><span>Option 1</span>
```

JS:

```
var $label = $('input[type=radio]').next();
$label.text('Options');
```

Comment: thanx for reply. But I am using Javascript... please suggest a solution in jscript.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly declare radio button like this

```
<input type="radio" id="rb" runat="server"/>
<label for="<%=rb.ClientID%>">option 1</label>
```

I mean use html radio button with `runat="server"` rather than `asp:RadioButton`, this will ensure rendering of control as it is and then try this

```
function JsChangeRBText(itemCheckBox, rbClientId)
{
   var optVal = document.getElementById(rbClientId);
   if(itemCheckjBox.checked)
   {
       optVal.nextSibling.value = 'abc';
    }       
   else
   {
       optVal.nextSibling.value = 'xyz';
    }       
}
```

Comment: @ Pawan Nogariya but this is an hTML control.. Is possible to change the text of radio button using asp control.

Comment: You will be able to access it in the code behind as it is runat="server" control.

Comment: <asp:RadioButton ID="rb" runat="server" CssClass="chk" Text="All"   Checked="true" />  I am using this as asp control. is there any problem in this code.

Comment: asp:RadioButton is rendered differently in different browsers, so just for the safety point of view we should use html radio button

Answer (score 1):

i know that question has been resolved but posting this solution in case it is useful for other.

But here i have used Jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Function JsChangeRBText(itemCheckBox, rbClientId)
    {
       var optVal = document.getElementById(rbClientId);
       if(itemCheckjBox.checked)
       {
            $("label[for='" + rbClientId + "']").text('abc');
        }       
       else
       {
            $("label[for='" + rbClientId + "']").text('xyz');
        }       
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but it I guess this should work. Please do reply if it is not working.

```
<asp:CheckBox
         ID="CheckBox1"
         runat="server"
         Text="Set Radio Checked"
         OnCheckedChanged="setText(this, document.getElementById('RadioButton1'))"
         AutoPostBack="true"
 />
<asp:RadioButton   
         ID="RadioButton1"   
         runat="server"  
         Text="Red"  
         GroupName="group1" 
/>

<script runat="server">  
    protected void setText(checkBox, radioBtn)  
    {  
        if (checkBox.Checked == true) {  
            radioBtn.Text = "abc";
        }  
        else{  
            radioBtn.Text = "xyz";
        }
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function JsChangeRBText(itemCheckBox, rbClientId)
{
   var optVal = document.getElementById(rbClientId);
   var label =  optVal.nextSibling;
   if(itemCheckjBox.checked)
   {
     label.textContent = "adc"; 
   }       
   else
   {
     label.textContent = "ccc";
   }       
}
```

Use textContent. This work for me.